# Xcode creates multiple test class instances to run tests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

I have always assume that for a given test class, Xcode will create a single object of that class and then run the tests sequentially. But when I tried with this example (the parallel tests option of this scheme is off), it looks like Xcode is creating multiple instances of the test class and then run the tests on them independently from each other.

Would this effectively eliminate the need for `tearDown` as the instance is thrown away anyway.

```
final class ExampleTests: XCTestCase {
    private let dataStorage: DataStorage = {
        print("*** Creating data storage")
        return DataStorage()
    }()

    func test1() {
        print("*** Data storage value: \(dataStorage.number)")
        dataStorage.number += 1
        XCTAssertEqual(dataStorage.number, 2)
    }

    func test2() {
        print("*** Data storage value: \(dataStorage.number)")
        dataStorage.number += 1
        XCTAssertEqual(dataStorage.number, 2)
    }

    func test3() {
        print("*** Data storage value: \(dataStorage.number)")
        dataStorage.number += 1
        XCTAssertEqual(dataStorage.number, 2)
    }

    func test4() {
        print("*** Data storage value: \(dataStorage.number)")
        dataStorage.number += 1
        XCTAssertEqual(dataStorage.number, 2)
    }
}

class DataStorage {
    var number = 1
}
```

This is the result:

```
*** Creating data storage
*** Creating data storage
*** Creating data storage
*** Creating data storage
*** Data storage value: 1
*** Data storage value: 1
*** Data storage value: 1
*** Data storage value: 1
```

We can see that the data storage object is created multiple times -> multiple `ExampleTests` object was created.

I tried with 100 tests like this, and 100 objects were created before any test was run.

Comment: This is standard of every Xunit-style unit testing framework.

Comment: The purpose of `tearDown` is for you to run whatever steps you need to wrap up a test, not necessarily just to deallocate variables etc.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly your question is? Your observation that one new instance of your `XCTestCase` subclass is made for each test is correct, but I'm not really sure what you're asking, per se

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on the question, but I just want to confirm this is the expected behavior of xcode test framwork.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Looks like I've been living under this false assumption the whole time :D

Answer (score 1):

In xUnit, a separate instance is made for each test. And they are all created before any tests are run. This is why setUp and tearDown are important: they give you control over when to create and destroy objects. See [Most Swift Devs Are Wrong About XCTestCase tearDown…](https://qualitycoding.org/xctestcase-teardown/)